# Modify Azure Bot Framwork QNA Bot with suggestion cards

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

Does anyone know how I might modify say the `BasicQnAMakerDialog.csx` file to be able to respond with suggestion cards if a user types "help"?  I am using `QNAMaker` knowledge base linked to an `Azure BotFramework`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two blog posts which I believe will help you:

1) [QnA Maker with Rich Cards](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/08/25/qna-maker-rich-card-attachments-net/)

2) [QnA Maker with Suggested Actions](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/09/28/qna-maker-revisited-suggested-actions-app-insights/)

Assuming you're using the [Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices/) nuget package, 
Both articles detail how to override the QnAMakerDialog class to manage responses from your QnA maker service. A suggested action is just another type of card action.

As to how you can implement the 'help' question from a user specifically, you can also implement a scorable/global message handler, but if you'd like your QnA service to handle a response for when a user types in 'help', these articles should help you find what you need.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out!